# List Box Selected.value throwing null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

**Populated list box like this:**

```
if (ds != null)
{
    ListPreviousRecords.Items.Clear();

    ListPreviousRecords.DataSource = ds;
    ListPreviousRecords.DataTextField = "Date";
    ListPreviousRecords.DataValueField = "ID";
    ListPreviousRecords.DataBind();
}
```

**Get selected value:**

```
protected void ListPreviousRecords_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ListPreviousRecords.SelectedItem.Value != "")
    {
        int mySelectedValue = int.Parse(ListPreviousRecords.SelectedItem.Value);// throwing null exception
        loadPreviousDetails(mySelectedValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: check if SelectedItem.Value is '!= null'. Else you might run into your if-statement with a null value causing your exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this code in order to ensure that not null value is entered

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListPreviousRecords.SelectedItem.Value ))
{
...
}
```

And Ensure that `AutoPostBack="true"` is set on your control

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that the null exception is thrown because `SelectedItem` might be null and he tries to get the `.Value` of it.

Comment: Linus because you must ensure that your control is posted when you change value, for this case add AutoPostBack attribute

Comment: i'am happy to help you Veer B.Singh

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 if(ListPreviousRecords.SelectedItem.Value != "")
```

To:

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ListPreviousRecords.SelectedItem))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ListPreviousRecords.SelectedValue`.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ListPreviousRecords.SelectedValue)) {
    // ...
}
```